# Why iOS6 call private method before viewdidload?

Tags: ios, viewdidload

I got a problem.

That when I initial a Controller I used `initwithnib:bundle:` method and then I think this controller has been loaded to the memory. So I call its method `selectUnreadMessage` to change its header. But I found that `viewdidload` was called after `selectUnreadMessage`.

Some one can tell me why ? Thanks.

```
- (void)selectUnreadSegmentedHeaderButton {

    if ([YDNetworkingManager sharedNetworkingManager].badgeNumbers.count) {

        for (NSNumber *unreadMessagesCount in [YDNetworkingManager sharedNetworkingManager].badgeNumbers) {
            if (unreadMessagesCount.intValue > 0) {
                NSInteger index = [[YDNetworkingManager sharedNetworkingManager].badgeNumbers indexOfObject:unreadMessagesCount];
                self.segmentedHeader.selectedIndex = index;
                [self loadTableViewAtIndex:index];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code of my private method is above. This controller has the property SegmentedHeader to switch between different kinds of messages.

This method is called After the Controller which used this method as addSubView;

Comment: Not unless you can explain yourself better than that.  But keep in mind that the view is created on the first reference to it.  If selectUnreadMessage references the view, that will cause it to load.

Comment: But when I called initwithnib:bundle: method, I referenced to the Controller right?

Comment: initWithNib references the controller, but not the view.

Comment: And if this Controller named "MessagesViewController". And In another Controller if we write [self.view addSubView:messagesViewController.view] then the MessageViewController will call the ViewDidLoad method? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` method is called when view of Controller is preparing to be `addSubView` into another view. And when view of Controller was added, `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` will be called. If view of Controller is removed from superview, `viewWillDisAppear` and `viewDidDisAppear` will be called.

And view of Controller is added again, `viewDidLoad` will **NOT** be called. Other methods will call the same as I've said.

It means when you initial a Controller, `viewDidLoad` was not called immediately. This method will be called later. It is **lazy-loading**

Hope it useful!

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me why the methods I defined can be called before ViewDidLoad? So when the method named "selectUnreadMessage" was called caused the iOS to call the ViewDidLoad?

Comment: If you don't call your private method, Is `viewDidLoad` called? `viewDidLoad` is only called if something made view of your Controller is visible. Could you show code of your private method?

Comment: If you don't call your private method, is `viewDidLoad` called?

Comment: Yes it's called but I wonder why this private method can be called before viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

ViewController initialization is not creating view - viewcontroller's view is loaded lazily - when it's view is actually added to view hierarchy. So, `-viewDidLoad` method gets called when you access viewcontroller's `.view` property - thus, you may consider initializing your data structures in the init method (fetch data, allocate containers, setup default values, etc.) and later, when `-viewDidLoad` is called - apply you data to your views / UI.